# how to play different audio in different slides using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm trying to build a slide-like project. I'm using ferroSlider jquery plug-in and Popcorn.js. My project has some slides and each of them (almost all of them) has and audio tag (all audio tags are different). I would like to play the audio when each slide ends loading. FerroSlider provides an event "endslie" and a function ($.fn.ferroslider.getActualSlideId()) that returns current div. I'm able to get the current audio id but i'm not able to play it...
Any help would be more than apreciated. Thanx everyone.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).bind("endslide", function(){
          var slideactual=$.fn.ferroSlider.getActualSlideId();
          var audioactual=[];



          $(slideactual).find("audio").each(function(){audioactual.push(this.id);});
          if($(slideactual).children('audio').length>0){
          alert(audioactual);
         }

        });
```

http://www.alessandroferrini.it/lab/jQueryPlugins/ferroSlider/docs/docs.php

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the audio element. You can play the audio using the in built functions for the audio tag. There's on onLoad eventlistener. That will play as soon as the audio loads and you can even add pause and play buttons.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var audioElement = $(audioactual);

        audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
            audioElement.play();
        }, true);

        $('.play').unbind('click').click(function() {
            audioElement.play();
        });

        $('.pause').unbind('click').click(function() {
            audioElement.pause();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Add this code (within the document ready) into your callback function and the audio should play when it loads. And it'll bind

Comment: Thanxs for your quick answer, but it doesn't work. My divs slide on keydown (i should probably said that before, sorry). Anyway, I've tried your code, and the audio (not all the slides have audio), don't play. My first aproach was to use autoplay: if the div that's showing has audio, autoplay it, as soon the slide(the div) has loaded... I'm quite confused!!!! :-). thanx again

Comment: Try binding audioElement.play() to keydown.

Comment: audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
    audioElement.play();
}, true); This should have worked as soon as the audio loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to bind it to keydown(although I've tried it, thanx), because i'm using "endslide" event. What I try to do is: when the slide is loaded ("endslide") if that slide has an audio tag (that's why I've created audioactual var), play it. The endslide event is triggered on key down (as the slideshow runs on keydown). Maybe the problem is that audioactual returns me the id of the audio in the current slide("audio1_1", for instance, and not "#audio1_1)...